Snap object to axes
blender novice here.
I have an object that I need to align to the x and y axes (in this example the letter "a" added as text with a solidify modifier).


The only way that I found is to:

select the object
enter edit mode
select the vertex placed closer to the x axis
snap the cursor to selected vertex
enter object mode
set origin to 3D cursor
set the y value in the transform - location panel to 0
repeat every step for the y axis

Isn't there a faster way? 
Like a "do the magic of align the selected object to axes even if the cursor is on a random vertex" magic button.
Edit:
I need it to align them the axes so that I could align other objects the same way to create stamps



Not sure if there’s a better way, but why do you need this, if I may ask? There might be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do as a whole.

I need it to align them the axes so that I could align other objects the same way to create stamps. I edited the question to add a couple images of the desired result.

I don’t think I’ve ever seen a stamp where the letter was smack up against the edge like this. Are you sure you can’t have it in the middle with some margin?

Side note, you’re looking for something “bounding box” related. Maybe there’s a setting in the Snap menu… IDR.

That's an experimentmaybe it won't work but I'd like to try.
it could be ok even with a margin but how could I make so that the margin is the same on every letter? The problem seems to be the same

If you are willing to use Edit Mode, here's what you can do:
In the snapping options, set the Snap Base to Active. Then ⇧ Shift select Grid and Vertex targets:

Then all you have to do is select all the mesh with A, chose a vertex from with you want to snap and ⇧ Shift select it to set it active, and them move while holding ⎈ Ctrl to snap the mesh from the active vertex to the nearest grid point from your cursor:

